# String.fromCharCode to a different language

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
   evt = evt || window.event;
   var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
   var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
   alert("Character typed: " + charTyped);
};
```

I want to display the letter, but in another language. For example: If my keyboard now in French, but I want to display the letter as if my keyboard was now on English.

How do I do it?

Comment: You're going to have to make a mapping from keyboard to keyboard. There's not really an algorithm to do that.